# Ruby : Convert String to Float

Tags: ruby

I have 3 string variables that I need to add.
a = "5.21", b= "5.22" and c = "5.23".
When I try to add i get a string, I need the numerical value

I have tried the following

```
a = a.to_f => 5.2
b = b.to_f => 5.2
c = c.to_f => 5.2
sum = a + b + c => 15.6
```

How do i get output 15.66. please help

Comment: Are you sure your `a`, `b` and `c` parameters are not all set to "5.2"? ... seems like the #to_f method should return a different value. Maybe the values are changed by some line of code you didn't notice...?

Comment: I suspect you have one or more invisible characters in your strings. Try this and report the result: `.each_char { |c| puts c.ord }`.  Where did the values of `a`, `b` and `c` come from?

Answer (score 10):

Try taking advantage of Ruby's built in `Enumerable` methods. Try this:

```
a = "5.21"
b = "5.22"
c = "5.23"

[a, b, c].map(&:to_f).inject(:+)
#=> 15.66
```

Comment: i am using 2.0.0 and i am getting 15.6 using the above solution

Comment: Are you sure there's no other code modifying these variables? Also, are their values the same as the strings you gave? If there are other, non-Numeric characters in the string it can have unintended behavior. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_f

Comment: I am reading this value from an android app
Once i read the value from the app, just to makes sure its a string i am calling the  a = a.to_s.strip methods. then a = a.to_f. This still returns jus 5.0 although in this case the string was 5.00

Comment: Try printing `a` at each step in the process, including before you call `to_s.strip` on the number. If at some point you start seeing `a` with only one number after the decimal, you know the previous operation cut it off. Let me know what happens.